# In a sequence of numbers 1:100, use loop to print in R

Tags: r

When I want to to use a matrix 1:100 and print words when a value can be divided by:
2 (print "two")
5 (print "five")
both 2 and 5 (print "both")
or else print the number, what loop do I use?

This means as output I would get 1, "two", 3, "two", "five", "two", 7, "two", 9, "both".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like ["FizzBuzz in R"](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2017/05/fizzbuzz-in-r/) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjusting the code from [FizzBuzz in R](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2017/05/fizzbuzz-in-r/) to your requirements:

```
divisor <-
  function(number, string) {
    function(d) {
      if (d %% number == 0) string else ""
    }
  }
mod3er <- divisor(2, "two")
mod5er <- divisor(5, "five")
fizzbuzz <- 
  function(i) {
    res <- paste0(mod3er(i), mod5er(i))
    ifelse(res == "", i, ifelse(res == "twofive", "both", res))
  }
sapply(1:100, fizzbuzz)
```

Ouput in joodle.com:

```
  [1] "1"    "two"  "3"    "two"  "five" "two"  "7"    "two"  "9"    "both"
 [11] "11"   "two"  "13"   "two"  "five" "two"  "17"   "two"  "19"   "both"
 [21] "21"   "two"  "23"   "two"  "five" "two"  "27"   "two"  "29"   "both"
 [31] "31"   "two"  "33"   "two"  "five" "two"  "37"   "two"  "39"   "both"
 [41] "41"   "two"  "43"   "two"  "five" "two"  "47"   "two"  "49"   "both"
 [51] "51"   "two"  "53"   "two"  "five" "two"  "57"   "two"  "59"   "both"
 [61] "61"   "two"  "63"   "two"  "five" "two"  "67"   "two"  "69"   "both"
 [71] "71"   "two"  "73"   "two"  "five" "two"  "77"   "two"  "79"   "both"
 [81] "81"   "two"  "83"   "two"  "five" "two"  "87"   "two"  "89"   "both"
 [91] "91"   "two"  "93"   "two"  "five" "two"  "97"   "two"  "99"   "both"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (i in 1:100){
    if(i %% 2 == 0 & i %% 5 == 0){
        print("both")
    }
    else if(i %% 2==0){
       print("two")
    }
    else if (i %% 5 ==0){
        print("five")
    }
    else{
        print(i)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[1] 1
[1] "two"
[1] 3
[1] "two"
[1] "five"
[1] "two"
[1] 7
[1] "two"
[1] 9
[1] "both"
[1] 11
[1] "two"
[1] 13
[1] "two"
[1] "five"
[1] "two"
[1] 17
[1] "two"
[1] 19
[1] "both"
[1] 21
[1] "two"
[1] 23
[1] "two"
[1] "five"
[1] "two"
[1] 27
[1] "two"
[1] 29
[1] "both"
[1] 31
[1] "two"
[1] 33
[1] "two"
[1] "five"
[1] "two"
[1] 37
[1] "two"
[1] 39
[1] "both"
[1] 41
[1] "two"
[1] 43
[1] "two"
[1] "five"
[1] "two"
[1] 47
[1] "two"
[1] 49
[1] "both"
[1] 51
[1] "two"
[1] 53
[1] "two"
[1] "five"
[1] "two"
[1] 57
[1] "two"
[1] 59
[1] "both"
[1] 61
[1] "two"
[1] 63
[1] "two"
[1] "five"
[1] "two"
[1] 67
[1] "two"
[1] 69
[1] "both"
[1] 71
[1] "two"
[1] 73
[1] "two"
[1] "five"
[1] "two"
[1] 77
[1] "two"
[1] 79
[1] "both"
[1] 81
[1] "two"
[1] 83
[1] "two"
[1] "five"
[1] "two"
[1] 87
[1] "two"
[1] 89
[1] "both"
[1] 91
[1] "two"
[1] 93
[1] "two"
[1] "five"
[1] "two"
[1] 97
[1] "two"
[1] 99
[1] "both"
```